# Authenticate service caller with its Managed Identity in another service

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, microservices, azure-api-management

What is the state-of-the-art way to authenticate caller (an App Service/.NET Core WebAPI with its Managed Identity, not on behalf on a signed in user) in another App Service/.NET Core WebAPI (that also has its own Managed Identity)? I'd like to use Azure API Management to hide called service and as minimum keys as possible.

EDIT:

**API** App Service Azure Authorization/Active Directory Settings:[image]
API App Registratoins details:

[image]

App registration/API App/Authentication:

- Implicit grants - only ID tokens checked
- Supported account types - Single tenant

[image]

App registration/API App/Expose an API:

[image]

When I try to add a client application a got this (`d1d` is an end of my **client App Service managed id**):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need managed identity for your API, any [app registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app) will do. Set its [application id uri](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad#-create-an-app-registration-in-azure-ad-for-your-app-service-app) and use the [Azure.Identity nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Identity) to get a token with something like this:

```cs
var managedIdentityCredential = new ManagedIdentityCredential();
var scopes = new []{"{your api application id uri}/.default"}; // E.G: api://3a768fed-640b-420c-8b33-39c701c55199/.default
var accessToken = (await managedIdentityCredential.GetTokenAsync(new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(scopes))).Token;
```

Comment: Ok, the docs are a bit misleading. I came to a point where I can acquire a token in my Client App Service, API App Service requires authentication, and I got 401 `You do not have permission to view this directory or page.` when using bearer authentication. I can't find a place for setting permission to access my API. Could you help me?

Comment: @Wojteq please share your API auth setup code/config.

Comment: @Wojteq applications permission cannot be pre-authorized. It only works for delegated permissions. About the error is due the application being one of a special kind and not cannot be found as a regular one.

Comment: What do you mean that "applications permission cannot be pre-authorized"? Do you mean that it's impossible to do what I want? How does it work when I authorize my App Service in Azure Key Vault?
Could you tell me how I can achieve my goal?

Comment: @Wojteq [pre-authorization works with scopes (delegated permissions)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow#pre-authorized-applications) but not with application permissions (app roles). Key vault configuration keeps being the same.